# How to change jest.mock mock return value?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk

I'm mocking the aws-sdk so that I don't make calls to the real thing.

I'm trying to mock https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#changeMessageVisibility-property.  I'm trying to do this by setting a jest.mock at the top of my test file (if I put it inside a describe or a beforeAll block or something, it doesn't work - honestly not sure why)

```
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
    const SQSMocked = {
      changeMessageVisibility: jest.fn().mockReturnValue( {} ),
    };
    const configMocked = {
        update: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
    }
    return {
      SQS: jest.fn(() => SQSMocked),
      config: configMocked
    };
  });
```

The code I'm trying to test is:

```
//set visibility timeout to camera.ingest.retryIntr
await sqs.changeMessageVisibility({
    QueueUrl: sourceQueueURL, /* required */
    ReceiptHandle: record.receiptHandle, /* required */
    VisibilityTimeout: camera.ingest.retryIntr /* required */
}, (err) => {  
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
});
```

Note, the example signature of changeMessageVisibility from the docs above is:

```
sqs.changeMessageVisibility(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

For most of the tests, I don't care about the success or failure (I assume success and don't care about the response).  But I want to test what happens if an error occurs. For that I built this test:

```
test("Will log and error if changeMessageVisibilty attempt fails", async () => {
    errorSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(()=>null)
    await ingest.retryIngest(TEST_CONSTANTS.sqsIngestEventMessageWithTwoRecords)
    expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) 
})
```

However, the error isn't triggered because my mocked `sqs.changeMessageVisibilty` function isn't erroring.   Do I need to mock the callback aspect of the changeMessageVisibilty function?  How can I test the above code? (or how can I refactor the code to be testable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqs.changeMessageVisibilty.mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => callback(error))`. Then, pass a mocked error to the callback.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

var sqs = new AWS.SQS();

export function main() {
  sqs.changeMessageVisibility(
    {
      QueueUrl: 'STRING_VALUE',
      ReceiptHandle: 'STRING_VALUE',
      VisibilityTimeout: 1000,
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else console.log(data);
    }
  );
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const SQSMocked = {
    changeMessageVisibility: jest.fn(),
  };
  const configMocked = {
    update: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  };
  return {
    SQS: jest.fn(() => SQSMocked),
    config: configMocked,
  };
});

describe('72634741', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const sqsMock = new AWS.SQS();
    const errMock = new Error('fake error');
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    sqsMock.changeMessageVisibility.mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
      callback(errMock);
    });
    main();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(errMock, errMock.stack);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72634741/index.test.js (10.965 s)
  72634741
    ✓ should pass (18 ms)

  console.log
    Error: fake error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/72634741/index.test.js:20:21)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) Error: fake error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/72634741/index.test.js:20:21)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:845:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   85.71 |       50 |     100 |   83.33 |                   
 index.js |   85.71 |       50 |     100 |   83.33 | 14                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.574 s
```